# Rational Elienberg-Maclane Spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is it true that
$$
H^k(K(\mathbb{Z},n);\mathbb{Q})\cong H^k(K(\mathbb{Q},n);\mathbb{Q})
$$
for all $k$?

Comment: Yes, more precisely the map $K(\mathbb Z, n) \to K(\mathbb Q, n)$ induces a rational equivalence, i.e., an isomorphism on cohomology.